# How to stop any functionality of jquery if the browser is smaller than 900px

Tags: jquery

There is a Jquery slider that I need to disable when my browser gets to a certain width, which I can do, however I don't know how to disable the slider/jquery so it stops its functionality of sliding and instead will just show the html and css which im changing with media queries.

I'm going to use a if else statement for this but don't know what to put inside the if else statement for it to do nothing.

Thanks

Comment: youre trying to say if(browser size < 900) -> do nothing; else -> do something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you stop Jquery from working in other words how do you disable Jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15664135/how-do-you-stop-jquery-from-working-in-other-words-how-do-you-disable-jquery)

Comment: that link is to his own question, asked a different time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 900) {
        // Do your thing
    }
}).trigger('resize');
```

That will call everytime the window is resized. I'm triggering it once so that if it's already smaller it will run.

Comment: Does this require the browser to have a refresh for it to be implemented?

Comment: No. I'm triggering it once so that if it's already smaller it will run.